# How to link shared object file in eclipse android application project?

Tags: android, eclipse, openssl, libssl

I have cross compile libssl1.1.1q for arm android  on linux Host. I have the libraries
libssl.so shared library
libssl.so.1.1 shared object

I tried to use libssl.so in Eclipse Android application project ,  but how ever when i compile the  java application on the Android platform I have "unreferenced function ssl error shared object file libssl.so.1.1"

I have tried to add the shared object file in android.mk file but not useful

Looking forward  for ideas to resolve the problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will also need `libcryto.so.1.1` (Note please quote the error message verbatim, it is not "unreferenced function ssl error")

Comment: Added libcryto.so.1.1 as well.. the compilation doesnt succeed.

Comment: Please quote the error message verbatim, it is not "unreferenced function ssl error"